# Windows Managed account to report subscription file share

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Is it possible to used a Windows Managed account to access a file share in a Report subscription?

When creating a Windows file share report subscription, on Step 4 - Create a data-driven subscription, I must specify the Username and Password of the account which has access to the file share.  Can this be a Windows Managed Account and if so, what do I specify for the password to get the field to validate and allow me to move to the next screen?

Comment: I would see if it accepts blank password. Generally things pick up that it is a built in or special account like that.

Comment: When I try and put the managed account in the username and leave the password field blank, then click Next, the password textbox has a field validation and gives the error message: "A value is required."

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have not messed with the file share subscriptions so I had to set this up locally on my machine to mess with it. The only thing I can even come across in MSDN that talks about the username for this type of subscription is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872791.aspx):

> **Password:**  Specify the password for the Windows user name.

Out of that the only thing I can find is that it requires an actual user account with password. So it is not possible to use virtual or managed account.

[image]

The only way I could get this subscription to write to the UNC path was to enter a Windows User account. In this instance my own login. I was just running an [example SSRS report](http://advworks2012sssrs.codeplex.com/) against [AdventureWorks2012 database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330).